# Bash autocomplete to list file under certain directory and pass to next command

Tags: bash, autocomplete

Use case: I need to do export KEY=value_file or cat value_file frequently and there are a lot of files so that creating alias for each of them is not actionable.
Work flow:

```
XXX$: `name of the function, say ABC` SPACE
```

I will then press tab, and I want to see a list of files under certain directory. something like

```
XXX$: ABC "cursor still here"
filea fileb filec
filed filee filef
```

And finally I can complete my command

```
XXX$: ABC filee
```

I guess the function in my bash_profile would be something like, yet the following does not work.

```
complete -r ABC
ABC(){
  COMPREPLY=$(ls somedir)
  export KEY=$1
}
```

ps: what's right command to see `man complete`? I want to see manual for `complete` instead of general commands.

## EDIT

thanks to shelter, I figured out:

```
ABC(){
  select f in $(ls mydir);
  do
    export KEY=mydir/$f;
    break;
  done
}
```

And there is like another alternative:

```
ABC(){
  export KEY=mydir/$1
}
complete -W "$(ls mydir)" ABC
```

Comment: `select f in *.txt ; do echo $f selected  ; done` might be one approach for this. [Select Tutorial](https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Select_loop) . Good luck.

Comment: Sadly, this is all "builtin" to bash, so the only reference is the big bash manual. Try this subsection: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Programmable-Completion-Builtins